# Rails undefined method for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I get this error while clicking in form Log In button:

```
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

View with signup form is below:

```
  <%= form_for(:session, url: login_path) do |f| %> 
  <%= f.text_field :login, :placeholder => "login" %> 
  <%= f.password_field :password, :placeholder => "Password" %> 
  <%= f.submit "Log in", class: "btn-submit"%>
  <% end %>
```

SessionsController :

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

def new
end

def create
    @user = User.find_by_login(params[:login][:password])  ////ERROR LINE
    if @user && @user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
        session[:user_id] = @user.id
        redirect_to '/'
    else 
        flash.now[:danger] = 'err'
        redirect_to '/login'
    end
end

def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil 
    redirect_to '/'
end 
end
```

User controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
def new
    @users = User.new
end
def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save 
        session[:user_id] = @user.id 
        current_user = @user.id

        redirect_to @user
    else 
        redirect_to '/login' 
    end 
end
private
def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :login)
end
end
```

Routes:

```
  get 'logout' => 'sessions#destroy'
  post 'logout' => 'sessions#destroy'
  delete 'logout' => 'sessions#destroy'
  get 'login' => 'sessions#new' 
  post 'login' => 'sessions#create' 
  resources :users, :user_types
```

Also, I do not want to create 'signup' view - there should be no possibility to create user through website

Comment: Try `form_for(:session, url: login_path, :method => "post")  do |f|`. Can you post the full error message, including the line number, and the line where the error is occurring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your form, I don't think you have `params[:login]`. So it'll be nil and `params[:login][:password]` is evaluated to `nil[:password]`. That's why you have the error.

What you have, according to the form, should be `params[:session][:login]` and `params[:session][:password]`. So the only remaining question is how you implemented your User.find_by_login method.